# Create a RDA biplot using extracted RDA results and merge to graphs

Tags: r, ggplot2, rda

Currently trying to use extracted data to create two seperate RDA biplots. Using the code that follows:

```
p <- ggplot()
p + geom_vline(x=0,colour="grey50") +
    geom_hline(y=0,colour="grey50") +
    geom_text(data = PHYTOPLANKTON_coordinates_scaling_2, aes(x = RDA1, y = RDA2, 
          label=rownames(PHYTOPLANKTON_coordinates_scaling_2)), angle=45, size=3,
          colour = 'blue') +
    geom_segment(data = WQ_coordinates_scaling_2, aes(x = 0, y = 0, 
          xend = RDA1, yend = RDA2), size = 0.5, colour = 'red') +
    geom_text(WQ_coordinates_scaling_2, aes(x = RDA1, y = RDA2,
          label = rownames(WQ_coordinates_scaling_2)), size = 5, angle = 45, 
          vjust = 1, colour = 'violet') +
    theme_bw()
```

This results in:

> Error: unexpected '=' in: "    +     geom_text(data =
>   PHYTOPLANKTON_coordinates_scaling_2, aes(x = RDA1, y = RDA2, 
>                                                                       +                                        label="
>                       +               colour = 'blue') Error: unexpected ')' in "                    +               colour =
>   'blue')"

Comment: please edit your post according to SO guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

```
set.seed(123)
# Generate toy data
n <- 20
PHYTOPLANKTON_coordinates_scaling_2 <-
data.frame(RDA1 = rnorm(n), RDA2 = rnorm(n))
rownames(PHYTOPLANKTON_coordinates_scaling_2) <- LETTERS[1:n]    
k <- 4
WQ_coordinates_scaling_2 <-
data.frame(RDA1 = rnorm(k), RDA2 = rnorm(k))
rownames(WQ_coordinates_scaling_2) <- paste0("V",1:k)

# Plot data   
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot()
p + geom_vline(xintercept=0,colour="grey50") +
    geom_hline(yintercept=0,colour="grey50") +
    geom_text(data=PHYTOPLANKTON_coordinates_scaling_2, aes(x=RDA1, y=RDA2, 
          label=rownames(PHYTOPLANKTON_coordinates_scaling_2)), angle=45, size=3,
          colour = 'blue') +
    geom_segment(data=WQ_coordinates_scaling_2, aes(x = 0, y = 0, 
          xend = RDA1, yend = RDA2), size = 0.5, colour = 'red') +
    geom_text(data=WQ_coordinates_scaling_2, aes(x=RDA1, y=RDA2,
          label = rownames(WQ_coordinates_scaling_2)), size = 5, angle = 45, 
          vjust = 1, colour = 'violet') +
    theme_bw()
```

[image]